# How do I combine two query with different columns into one?

Tags: mysql

How do I combine these two queries into one table. They are two different results so I need them to be two different columns. I've tried UNION but that puts them into one column.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Number_Customers FROM customer
Where cus_balance > 0;
Select SUM(cus_balance) AS Total_Balances
FROM customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite them as subqueries, and use `DUAL` as the dummy table.

```
SELECT
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer WHERE cus_balance > 0) AS Number_Customers,
   (SELECT SUM(cus_balance) FROM customer) AS Total_Balances
FROM DUAL;
```

If the `WHERE` clauses may be the same, then you can simply write it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Number_Customers,
       SUM(cus_balance) AS Total_Balances
FROM Cusomers
WHERE cus_balance > 0;
```